# Prevent users from typing on html5 date textbox

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an asp:textbox which I set to textmode="date" and I managed to prevent users on selecting future dates by blocking them with:

```
txtDateofAcci.Attributes["max"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

and removed the spin arrows with:

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
     display: none;
     }
     </style>
```

I made this to prevent users from entering future dates, however, I can still enter future dates by typing it, Now, I want to prevent users or block them from typing, instead, input date by selecting through the picker. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the textbox control:

```
onkeypress="return false;"
```

Hope it helps...